# Where is the location of console fonts in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

Where is the location of console fonts in CentOS 7? Please tell me if somebody knows that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in `/usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts` which is owned by the `kbd-misc` package.