# How do I increase the font size of the CentOS 7 console?

Tags: centos, grub2, grub, console, fonts

When I booting to CentOS, the character is too small.
[image: Small character]

I tried to config grub2 files following [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised?newreg=91782d800af5464487c3eab8e45901a2), but it seems not work.

My /etc/default/grub file is :

[image]

So, how can I increase the font size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I would not touch your GRUB configuration files. Instead,  I would add a `setfont` line to your shell initialization file.

For example, if you are using Bash, you could ask the following line to `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ $TERM = linux ]
then
    setfont sun12x22
fi
```

There are lots of different fonts available; `sun12x22` is just one example. See the `setfont` man page for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advising. I put your code in the `/etc/profile.d/setfontsize.sh`, then every user can change his font size when login.

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this on a systemd operating system such as CentOS 7 is to edit the font settings in the `/etc/vconsole.conf` file.  These settings are applied by the `systemd-vconsole-setup` service, which is essentially a glorified way of running `setfont` and `loadkeys` before the login services are brought up.

So you would have `FONT=sun12x22` in that file, for example.

Note that the service program allows kernel command-line options such as `vconsole.font` to override `/etc/vconsole.conf` contents.  If you are mucking around with GRUB kernel command-line options, bear this in mind.

## Further reading

- [Where is the location of console fonts in CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196064/)
- Lennart Poettering et al.. [`vconsole.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/vconsole.conf.html).  systemd manual pages.  FreeDesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al.. [`systemd-vconsole-setup`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-vconsole-setup.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  FreeDesktop.org.
- sles (2014-07-09).  *[systemd doesn't set console font](https://bugs.centos.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=7325)*.  CentOS Bug #7325.
- [Setting console font in vconsole.conf does not work (systemd)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57085/)
- [Can I change the font of terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/)

Comment: That works! I use `ls /usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts | grep 32` to find a `latarcyrheb-sun32` font. Then edit the `/etc/vconsole.conf` file to change FONT to this font. And also edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-vconsole-setup.service` file, change `After=sysinit.target` and `Before=shutdown.target`, then reboot. Then the font has changed before login.

Comment: The problem is that this approach changes the default font for all users.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Install terminus console font: :-)

Terminus console font is in EPEL repository.

yum install epel-release
yum install terminus-fonts-console.noarch

### 2. Directly in a Terminal (tty x):

Displays usable fonts for the terminal:
ls /usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts

Changes the font directly in the terminal:
setfont sun12x22

if you are using Bash, you could get the following line to .bash_profile:
if [ $TERM = linux ]
then
setfont sun12x22
fi

### 3. Resolution - to /etc/default/grub:

video=800x600

### 4. Systemd

Edit /etc/vconsole.conf:
FONT="ter-v32n"

Edit /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-vconsole-setup.service
systemctl status systemd-vconsole-setup.service
systemctl cat systemd-vconsole-setup.service
systemctl edit systemd-vconsole-setup.service

Change the After= and Before= lines to:

After=sysinit.target
Before=shutdown.target

### 5. Check /boot/grub2/grub.cfg and/or /etc/default/grub.

If grub.cfg contains a vconsole.font parameter, delete that parameter.

[reprinted from this link](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=69149)